# Adding Custom JQuery Menu Fresh Slide Out

Tags: php, jquery

TBH this is my first time doing as adding a custom `jquery` in a `wordpress` and i read like about 10-20 articles about it already and more i guess but there still something missing, so i did it like this, and please mention what Im doing wrong, and the jquery im adding is found [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/03/09/a-fresh-bottom-slide-out-menu-with-jquery/).

Here is the snippet of what i want,

```
<div class="container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a>
                        <i class="icon_about"></i>
                        <span class="title">About</span>
                        <span class="description">Learn about us and our services</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the code I added into `function.php` in the `wordpress` theme,

function my_custom_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/css/style.css' );

wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_function' );

I added this too in the `header.php` as I saw in the sample index.php of the slider its on the head so i assume it is needed,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#menu > li').hover(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                            'bottom':'-15px'
                        }, 300);
                    $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                            'top':'-10px'
                        }, 400);
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                            'bottom':'-95px'
                        }, 300);
                    $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                            'top':'50px'
                        }, 400);
                }
            );
        });
   </script>
```

And this `php` snippet is where im getting my menu's,

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu=header_menu&container=false'); ?>
```

from all of this, i just wanted to know if what im doing wrong and now what i needed to do next, pretty much a newbie here in this jquery integration, just did this today. And in my mind the thing im missing too is in the last `php` code where i need to include the `id="menu"` but thats the thing too, how do i add it.

And BTW has anyone successfully implemented the `Fresh Slide Out` please help me, even though im just learning I still need to successfully implement it to go to other jquery and try them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Wyck's answer, since you asked if you are doing anything wrong, I'd suggest that it is usually more correct to register and enqueue your scripts as you've already done with some scripts in `my_custom_function`, than it is to write scripts directly into the header.

That is, put this code:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#menu > li').hover(
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                        'bottom':'-15px'
                    }, 300);
                $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                        'top':'-10px'
                    }, 400);
            },
            function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                        'bottom':'-95px'
                    }, 300);
                $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                        'top':'50px'
                    }, 400);
            }
        );
    });
```

...in a `.js` file and enqueue it like you did with the `flex-script`.

If you register and enqueue correctly you can save yourself some effort. For example:

```
function my_custom_function() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/css/style.css' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'flex-script', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_function' );
```

You don't need that `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`. jQuery is listed as a dependency of your `flex-script`. It will load automatically. You can do the same with your `flex-script` and your additional code.

```
function my_custom_function() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript/css/style.css' );

        wp_register_script( 'flex-script', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/javascript/flex-script-name.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

        wp_register_script( 'my-flex-code', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/javascript/my-flex-code-name.js', array( 'flex-script' ), false, true );

        wp_enqueue_script('my-flex-code');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_function' );
```

That last line -- `wp_enqueue_script('my-flex-code');` -- should enqueue all of the dependent scripts.

I noticed that you registered `flex-script` as an old version of jQuery-- `/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js`. I assume that is a mistake. you should not be using old jQuery, much less loading the Core jQuery and also another jQuery. That is bound to cause trouble.

As far as including `id="menu"`, I am not sure where your Javascript needs that ID to be but I am fairly sure that Wyck is on the right track.

The following should do what you want:

```
wp_nav_menu(
  array(
    'container_class' => 'container',
    'menu_id' => 'menu'
  )
);
```

That should, and does, generate what should do what you want if and only if your description of what you need is correct:

```
<div class="container">
        <ul id="menu" class="menu">
```

Comment: Hey I'm not Milo:)

Comment: Many, many apologies!! I'll fix that.

Comment: @s_ha_dum : I have done the integration of the jquery into wordpress until that, but what im missing now is the if the `id="menu"` that is inside the `<ul>` and the `<div id="container">` , i dont really know how to make them.

Comment: You did get (probably) functioning Javascript but you also asked "what im doing wrong". I told you.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: i think Im going to surrender, it seems i cant possible add the stinking `jquery` :(
and thanx very much for the time and help

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the Codex page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu, `wp_nav_menu`  takes a number of parameters including one for the `id`.

```
'menu_class'      => 'my-menu',
'menu_id'         => 'menu',
```

Comment: `'menu'            => 'header_menu',
'menu_id'         => 'container',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="menu"><li><span class="title">%3$s</span></li></ul>'`
I did like this but still i couldnt have a result the same as my snippet. Need help if you dont mind